# When executing a run configuration, JetBrains software does not seem to be using the Ruby version I specified

Tags: ruby, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, rubymine, run-configuration

I am trying to run a "Run configuration". However in the run window, I get a message:

> Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.2

So I go to the Terminal tab and I do `rvm use 2.5.2`. That works fine.

Then I try running the preconfig again, and I get the same error.
It seems what I did it Terminal does not get picked up by the preconfig.

How do I get it to recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Settings -> Ruby SDK and Gems -> select the correct Ruby version and click apply.

Comment: No, you can find this in the Jetbrains IDE

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, I was distracted and wrote the wrong thing.
I don't see any Ruby SDK settings in Webstorm

Comment: Webstorm is by default trying to find a android SDK. Don't think it even supports Ruby. If you want to use ruby, use Rubymine.